# C++ Shell function to get CSIDL for a public library folder

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I was wondering, on a Windows platform is there any API/CSIDL to retrieve the Library folder path for the Public user account?

Path like this: "C:\Users\Public"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use environment variables for this. Use the correct API for this, which is [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx).

To get the path to the public folder, pass `FOLDERID_Public` as the first parameter to SHGetKnownFolderPath.

If you need to support pre-Vista operating systems as well, use [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx) instead, passing `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` as the first param.